# where do I find ckeditor's default style?

Tags: ckeditor

my documents are looking good in the CKeditor's textarea field. But when using the so generated HTML-files it doesn't look good. No wonder: there are no CSS styles saved in the HTML.

Which css files do I have to include to display ckeditor's HTML files looking similar to those within the editor? Or can I make Ckeditor include it's styles information in the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Use `contents.css`, located in your ckeditor root folder.